# Integro-differential equation including a convolution of the first derivative.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution, boundary-value-problem, integro-differential-equations

I am having difficulty finding the right approach to solving the following differential equation,
$$
y''(t)+\int_t^Tg(s-t)y'(s)\,ds=f(t),
$$
with the boundary conditions,
$$y(0)=y_0\,,\quad y(T)=0.$$
I considered representing $y(t)$ using a Fourier series, but term-wise differentiation is not guaranteed because the periodic extension of $y(t)$ isn't 
differentiable at the boundaries $t=0,T$.

What approach is the smartest to solve this equation? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but can you subtract off the boundary by writing $y(t) = u(t) + \frac{y_0}{T}(T-t)$? Then due to linearity, $u(t)$ would satisfy a very similar equation

Comment: @Dylan I considered that too. In that case, the first derivative of the Fourier series would indeed converge to $y'(t)$, but $y'(0) = y'(T)$ is not guaranteed so the second derivative of the Fourier series would NOT converge to $y''(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $v(t) = y'(t)$. Thus $y(t) = - \int_t^T v(s) \, ds$.

Now solve the first order integrodifferential equation
$$
v'(t)+\int_t^Tg(s-t)v(s)\,ds=f(t), \; v(T) = \alpha
$$
for general $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. The solution may be expressed in the form
$$
v(t) = \alpha r(t) + \int_t^T r(s-t)f(s)\, ds = \alpha r(t) + \tilde f(t)
$$
where $r$ is known as *differential resolvent*  (see monographs on integral equations, e.g. Gripenberg - Londen - Staffans, CUP 1990, Theorem 3.1). Therefore 
$$
y(t) = - \int_t^T v(s) ds = - \alpha \int_t^T r(s) ds - \int_t^T \tilde f(s) \,  ds 
$$
Set $t = 0$ to find the right value of $\alpha$. This gives a unique solution if $\int_0^T r(t) \, dt \ne 0$. If $\int_0^T r(t) \, dt = 0$, there either are infinitely many solutions or there is no solution, depending on whether $\int_0^T \tilde f(s) + y_0 = 0$ or not.